# mysql - replication lag

Tags: mysql, replication

I have problem with mysql replication. Alarm trap turned me different position beetwen Read_Master_Log_Pos and Position (difference of 1). This condition lasted about half an hour. Anyone knows how to solve and analyze this problem?

Comment: Not really giving us much information to work with now are you

Comment: Not a Stack Overflow question. This is an issue with a server. Maybe [ask on the DBA site](http://dba.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score -1):

It's possibly a network or communications issue. You can use network analyzer tools (such as tcpdump, with appropriate filters to limit volume) to figure out what is going on. We need more info to be able to help further.

Comment: At best this is a comment. It is in no way an answer to a question that even you admit cannot be answered without a lot more information

Comment: They wanted to know how to solve and analyze the problem, and I proposed a way to go about doing that based on the limited info given. I don't see how that's "No way an answer". Way #1: area to look for trouble proposed. Way #2: Tool proposed to analyze given trouble. 2 ways is not 0 ways.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Tips from Jeremy are very useful for me.
Best Regards.